# Fix DIV Geometry to Browser 100% Aside other Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, layout, css-position

http://jsbin.com/iGIToRuV/1/edit

I'm working on a WYSIWYG website designer as an experiment for a variety of reasons. (The plan is to make this desktop and mobile friendly)

One issue I'm having is getting the div#canvas to be 100% via width and height. In addition I don't even see the div#canvas on Firefox either, and unsure as to why that is.

Let me elaborate...

My div#canvas is positioned where I want it. My div.options is positioned on the right:0; and it's width is 291px. I want to tell my div#canvas to fill the page width so it covers the body, but doesn't exceed past it.

I explained the best I could, but to understand more visually, here's a design prototype I made for this post.
[image]

**The HTML**:

```
<body>
    <header class="header">Links</header>
    <div class="toolbox">Tools</div>

    <div class="content" id="canvas"></div>

    <div class="options">Options</div>
</body>
```

**The CSS**:

```
/* Canvas */
#canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:81px; left:44px;
    width:100%; height:100%;
}

.header {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    width:100%; height:81px;
}

.toolbox, .options {
    position:absolute;
    top:81px; height:100%;
}

.toolbox { left:0; width:44px; }
.options { right:0; width:291px; }
```

Comment: Please try to include only the relevant parts of your code, not the whole jsbin demo.

Comment: I modified it so now only relevant code shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify all the four dimensions and it will stretch your canvas:

```css
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 81px; left:44px; right: 291px; bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know you could add more than two. I've always done top left/right, or bottom left/right. ... I tested this and it too isn't working.

Comment: Strange, let me try in this jsbin. You can use all 4 at the same time freely (one of my favorite tricks, even though it is not a big trick), the problem must be something else.

Comment: @mikethedj4 Forgot to tell that you should remove the width 100% and height 100% of course. [It works that way](http://jsbin.com/iGIToRuV/5).

Comment: Thank you very much bro. This little trick has been pretty helpful.